# Cube partition refresh using C# AMO object - Async way

Tags: c#, azure, azure-analysis-services

I want to Refresh the cube partition using `C# AMO` object , synchronous way of refreshing partition is happening fine. But I wanted to refresh partitions parallelly. For that I tried by calling refresh method inside

`Parelle.ForEach()`.

```
templatePartition.RequestRefresh(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType.Full);
database.Model.SaveChanges();
```

But it is giving error that   :

> Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The lock operation ended unsuccessfully because of deadlock.

So wanted to check anyone did partition refresh using AMO calling asynchronously.

Comment: SSAS supports parallel operations just fine, but generally only if you ask *it* to parallelize the operations, not when you start parallelizing from the client side. In XMLA, you do this by putting the commands in a `<Parallel>` element inside the `<Batch>`. In AMO, I have no idea if this is possible. From what I can glean it isn't *really*, and you need to use `.CaptureXml` to get the XMLA for the individual statements and cobble together the XMLA manually to submit through `Server.Execute`.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for the response. XMLA i saw few example, but i didn't get any help using AMO. I will have to use AMO object to do automation. LEt me try with **Server.Execute**.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen mentioned, the correct way to do this is to allow SSAS to handle the parallelization so you don't run into deadlocks or other issues that come from processing partitions in the wrong order.

You can make use of the `CaptureLog` property in order to [implement this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.core.server.executecapturelog?view=analysisservices-dotnet) in AMO. The capture log collects the statements you want to run, and then `ExecuteCaptureLog` to run them all. The second parameter on `ExecuteCaptureLog` denotes whether or not the processes will be run in parallel.

```
static public XmlaResultCollection RunWithCaptureLog(Server server, string dbName)
{
    if ((svr != null) && (svr.Connected))
    {
        svr.CaptureXml = true;

        #region Actions to be captured to an XMLA file  
        foreach (Table table in server.Databases.GetByName(dbName).Model.Tables)
        {
            foreach (Partition partition in table.Partitions){
                partition.RequestRefresh(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType.Full);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        svr.CaptureXml = false;

        //public Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaResultCollection ExecuteCaptureLog (bool transactional, bool parallel, bool processAffected)
        return svr.ExecuteCaptureLog(true, true, true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Samara.. let me give a try.